# Want to get the hourly working emplyeess count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to know the hourly working employess count

they can log in different.

[image]

Comment: So how would you identify hourly employees? What functions could then get the result? A count? There are several count functions. Check out what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try `SUMPRODUCT()` in this way.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR($C$3:$C$8)<=G3)*(HOUR($D$3:$D$8)>=G3))
```

[image]

Comment: Sharing the error screen short please check and help me

Comment: @SurendraDonekal You post screenshot and error screenshot doesn't match.

Comment: Then try `=SUMPRODUCT(($AG:$AG<=AJ2)*($AH:$AH>=AJ2))`

Answer (score 0):

=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR($AG:$AG)<=AJ2)*(HOUR($AH:$AH)>=AJ2))

I use this formula but showing #VALUE! error,Please check once.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZQNN.png)

Comment: #harun24hr please check the give snap and help me

Comment: Remove hour() function if your input is only number instead of time.

Answer (score 0):

If have data and time stamp then how can calculate the count of employees.

Image:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShwN6.png)

#Harun24hr

Comment: mentioned data instead of date ,it's my bad,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).